# Django ORM - percent sign for like

Tags: sql, django, orm, django-queryset

On my site user should have an ability to filter numbers, like `*123*321*`, that will match "666 *123* 555 *321* 111" or `LIKE '%123%321%'`.

By default django's orm escapes [%-sign](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#escaping-percent-signs-and-underscores-in-like-statements). I can use regex, or raw query, but is there some workaround?

UPD: i'll place it here for displaying another way.

```
integer_search = [] # for colorizing found substrings
if actual['integer']:
    integer_match = filter(None, actual['international'].split('*'))
    integer_search = integer_match
    integer_match = ''.join('%s[[:digit:]]*' % i for i in integer_match)
    integers = integers.filter(international__regex=integer_match)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Django replaces all the `%` and `_`. From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#escaping-percent-signs-and-underscores-in-like-statements):

> This means things should work intuitively, so the abstraction doesn't
>   leak. For example, to retrieve all the entries that contain a percent
>   sign, just use the percent sign as any other character

I would recommend you to use [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) method. It is not really raw sql, although looks hacky:

```
YourModel.objects.extra(where=['title LIKE %s'], params=['%123%321%'])
```

Comment: If you use this idea then check you are not creating an SQL injection attack.

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood Yes, `params` prevents it.

Comment: I just want to note, i think, if some tool disables original functionality, it should be a way to enable it with a method similar to that func's idea. I mean, that `__icontains=''` method already takes an argument, so why don't just to disable escaping in a place, like `.filter(field__icontains='%1', field__pescape=False)`? When i use extra() i go further. I just want to understand: django's developers skipped this because it's outside of django's philosophy, or this ability is not in a first-need list? Anyway, thanks, i'll mark your answer.

Comment: I don't like your suggestion, but you can [offer](https://code.djangoproject.com/) it to the community