# How can I prevent SQL injection in PYTHON-DJANGO?

Tags: python, sql, django, security, sql-injection

If a lamer input is inserted into an SQL query directly, the application becomes vulnerable to SQL injection, like in the following example:

```
dinossauro = request.GET['username']

sql = "SELECT * FROM user_contacts WHERE username = '%s';" % username
```

To drop the tables or anything -- making the query:

```
INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES('`**`value'); DROP TABLE table;--`**`')
```

What may one do to prevent this?

Comment: May I ask you why are you manually writing sql queries instead of using django Models?

Comment: The django ORM, outside of `raw` and `extra` will escape your queries for you. See the [security docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/security/#sql-injection-protection).

Answer (score 13):

First, you probably should just use [Django ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/), it will prevent any possibility of SQL injection.

If for any reason you can't or don't want to then you should use [Python Database API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/). Here is the way you usually do that in Django:

```
from django.db import connection

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('insert into table (column) values (%s)', (dinosaur,))
cursor.close()
```

You can also use [handy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/handy) python package to reduce the boilerplate:

```
from handy.db import do_sql

do_sql('insert into table (column) values (%s)', (dinosaur,))
```

Answer (score 5):

From the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/security/#sql-injection-protection):

> SQL injection protection
>
> SQL injection is a type of attack where a
>   malicious user is able to execute  arbitrary SQL code on a database.
>   This can result in records being deleted or data leakage.
>
> By using Django’s querysets, the resulting SQL will be properly
>   escaped by the underlying database driver. However, Django also gives
>   developers power to write raw queries or execute custom sql. These
>   capabilities should be used sparingly and you should always be careful
>   to properly escape any parameters that the user can control. In
>   addition, you should exercise caution when using extra().

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `.extra()` the syntax is:

```
YourModel.objects.extra(where=['title LIKE %s'], params=['%123%321%'])
```

Repeating here from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10810873/1308967) as this is hard to find, and the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/security/#sql-injection-protection) that say `"you should always be careful to properly escape any parameters"` do not go on to say *how* to properly escape them!